# i3WM: How to select a window with both class and name simultaneously?

Tags: i3-wm

My i3 config file includes the next line:

```
for_window [title="Error"] kill; floating enable; border none
```

Which makes every single window with the word "Error" (case sensitive) to be closed once it opens.

The only error window I want to close after opening is the one with class "`Lxpolkit`" as shown in the next `xprop` results:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "lxpolkit", "Lxpolkit"
```

Does anyone know a way to select such window by both name and class simultaneously?

Something like:

```
for_window [title="Error"] and [class="Lxpolkit"] kill; floating enable; border none
```

Comment: Try this `for_window [title="Error" class="Lxpolkit"]`. Also check official [documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#configuring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there. Try

```
for_window [title="Error" class="Lxpolkit"] kill; floating enable; border none
```

Comment: Boooom!!! My brain explodes... Thank you